# Jenkins: MSTest: Unable to specify mutiple test result files to be converted to JUnit XML format

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins, fileset, jenkins-mstest

While automating build process using Jenkins, we are using MSTest plugin to convert the generated *.trx files to JUnit xml format so that it can be shown in build report.
This plugin is working fine with a single file. eg: MyProject/TestResults.trx. (%WORKSPACE% is implicit as used by the plugin)

But now since we have multiple(2) test project for the same application.(integration & unit)
I want to combine both the test results and show the combined result.

For that I am trying the following Ant Fileset pattern.

```
<fileset dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinsJobWorkSpaceDir\">   
<filename name="*.trx" /> 
</fileset>
```

But this is not working showing the following message:

[MSTEST-PLUGIN] No MSTest TRX test report files were found. Ignoring.

Here are my two files:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinsJobWorkSpaceDir\TestResult1.trx
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinsJobWorkSpaceDir\TestResult2.trx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per instruction given under the text box for file in mstest plugin for jenkins:

[image: MSTest Plugin Jenkins]

it says Ant fileset pattern, which doesn't mean including that fileset tag instead use wildcard expression to include all the files in a folder.